# Removed initial view controller from Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've removed initial view pointer (-> arrow which decides first view) from storyboard, am setting it programmatically. Since my app should load tutorial if it's first launch & from next time it should go to login .

I've done that using code, but now when am working on other screens & I want to test that particular screen only, am coming from all the screen in flow till that screen. When am setting that screen which I want to test as initial view, nothing is happing since I've overridden that functionality with my code, but I'll need that to set any screen as initial view temporarily for testing purpose.

Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: you could just comment out the block of code that sets the initial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let entryPoint = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = entryPoint
```

Whichever `Initial View Controller` you assign, this will pick that one particularly.

Comment: Above answer will work but need to add "Main" in front of "Main storyboard file name" key, in plist file. Bcz it was removed, since it was coming from code.